# Mutt not attaching multiple files and sending attachment to server in python

Tags: python, linux, email, csv, mutt

So, I'm trying to use mutt to attach all .csv files in a folder and it's not cooperating. For some reason, it only attaches one of them and I thought I was doing it correctly. On a stranger note, mutt also sends the one .csv it actually attaches to the server. And by that I mean, I receive an e-mail to my email with one file attached and also in the "To:" field it has the .csv file@server I.E "To: MyCsvFile.csv@server.serv.net; myemail@domain.com". So, it sends to the e-mail I want it to send it to, on top of the server...why is it sending to the server and only attaching one .csv?

```
def sendEmail():
    email = 'myemail@domain.com'
    Extracts = "/path/path/path/path/path/*.csv"
    blankEmailContentFile = '/path/path/path/path/blank'

    fh = open(blankEmailContentFile, 'w+')
    fh.close()

    linuxCMD = 'mutt -s "Email Subject" -a %s "%s" < %s' % (Extracts, email, blankEmailContentFile )
    os.system(linuxCMD)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mutt` command line is incorrect.  According to the `mutt(1)` man page:

```
   -a file [...]
          Attach  a  file  to  your message using MIME.  When attaching single or multiple files,
          separating filenames and recipient addresses with  "--"  is  mandatory,  e.g.  mutt  -a
          image.jpg  --  addr1  or  mutt  -a img.jpg *.png -- addr1 addr2.  The -a option must be
          placed at the end of command line options.
```

Without the `--` separating the filenames from the addresses, `mutt` is interpreting everything but the first filename as a destination address.  Your command line should look something like:

```
linuxCMD = 'mutt -s "Email Subhect" -a %s -- "%s" < %s' % (Extracts, email, blankEmailContentFile )
```

While the above will work, this would be a good opportunity to look into the `subprocess` module and figure out how to build a command line that did not rely on shell wildcard expansion in order to operate correctly.  There is also an `smtplib` module for Python that would allow you to send email without relying on an external program.

Comment: Thanks larks, but the command behaves exactly the same with or without the " -- ". It's still only attaching one file and sending the file to the server. At any rate, I did add the " -- " in the command for better practice.